# How to split a string into a list at irregular intervals

Tags: python

I'm trying to split a string by using a list of intervals, inserting a space before the first interval value corresponding to the index of the character and a space after the 2nd interval value corresponding to the index of the character.

I know how to split a string at regular intervals:

```py
string = 'anexample'
result = []
for i in range(0, len(string), 2):
    result.append(' ')
    result.append(line[i:i+2])
result = [' ','an',' ','ex',' ','am',' ','pl',' ','e']
```

but I'm not sure how I would go about it with an interval list such as this:

```py
string = 'anexample'
result = []
interval_list = [[0,0],[2,5]]
```

and end up with this result:

```py
result = [' ','a',' ','n',' ','exam',' ','ple']
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**Edit**: The interval_list is derived from comparing characters in a list to the string, for example:

```py
string = 'anexample'
word_list = ['exam']
interval_list = [[2,5]]
```

where string[2] = 'e' and string[5] = 'm'. Adding a space before the 'e' and after the 'm' would give:

```py
result = ['an',' ','exam',' ','ple']
```

Comment: What's your `interval_list` mean?

Comment: My interval_list contains the range of indices of existing characters, in this example I have the word 'exam' in another list, which corresponds to index 2 to 5 of the string 'anexample'.

Comment: @tiqtoq so you want to split the string on the basis of intervals?

Comment: @DirtyBit correct, so if I had the string 'example' and an interval [2,4], I would split the string like so: 'ex' + space + 'amp' + space + 'le', adding a space before the 2nd index in the string and after the 4th.

Comment: And why is your interval list nested? what's `[0, 0]`?

Comment: BTW what you are inserting/adding is not a `space` sign (`' '`) but an empty string (`''`).

Comment: @SpghyyCd It's nested because I have multiple words that match with the string. The interval [0,0] is the position of the word 'a' in 'anexample' where the first 0 is the lower position of the word and the second 0 is the upper position of the word. If I used 'n' instead of 'a', the interval would be [1,1].

Comment: @SpghttCd My bad, I'll correct that.

Comment: Ok, understood - but we both know that the first word in `anexample` is `an`, not `a`, right? It's just - let me guess - some ML/DL/AI/whatever... which does not...

Comment: @SpghttCd You're right, however I'm treating single characters such as 'a' or 'n' as words for the purpose of my program.

Comment: My point was: neither a nor n are single characters here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the intervals are always listed in order:

```
string = 'anexample'
result = []
interval_list = [[0,0],[2,5]]

for i,interval in enumerate(interval_list):
    # append the part of the string before the first interval (if any)
    if i < 1 and interval[0] > 0:
        result.append(string[0:interval[0]])

    result.append(' ')
    result.append(string[interval[0]:interval[1]+1])
    result.append(' ')

    # append the part of the string before the next interval (if any)
    if i < len(interval_list) - 1 and (interval_list[i+1][0]>interval[1]+1):
        result.append(string[interval[1]+1:interval_list[i+1][0]])

    # append the rest of the string to result
    elif i == len(interval_list) - 1 and i < len(string)-1:
        result.append(string[interval[1]+1:len(string)])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[' ', 'a', ' ', 'n', ' ', 'exam',' ', 'ple']
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your `interval_list` is more than uncomfortable. It should look like

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 6, 9]
```

Then you can simply do

```
for a, b in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:]):
    result.extend([' ', string[a:b]])

# print(result)
# [' ', 'a', ' ', 'n', ' ', 'exam', ' ', 'ple']
```

and you're done.

---

If you don't have influence on the structure of `interval_list`, you can calculate this better suitable list via

```
lst = [i for sub in interval_list for i in sub]
for i in range(1, len(lst), 2):
    lst[i] += 1
lst += [len(string)]

# [0, 1, 2, 6, 9]
```

or if you perhaps have numpy imported anyway

```
lst = np.array(interval_list).flatten()
lst[1::2] += 1
lst = np.append(lst, len(string))
```

Comment: In my case the intervals I want to split for are exclusively grouped, in my example the interval list in your format would look like `lst = [0,0,2,5]`. The `for a,b in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:])` line gives intervals (0,0), (0,2) and (2,5), when I only need (0,0) and (2,5).

Comment: No. Sorry, but you completely misunderstood the whole thing, please read carefully again. 1. In your example the interval list in my format looks like `lst = [0, 1, 2, 6, 9]`, i.e.: first starting index (0), first ending index (0+1, because in python indexing is _including start index_ and _excluding stop index_), then second start index (2), then second stop index (5+1), and a trailing additional index which is the length of the string (9). 2. Knowing this and the fact that you can't change your list I even proposed to you a short "converter": just run these 4 lines and you have `lst`...

Comment: My mistake, misunderstood the formatting of lst. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. But now i think you see what I meant by uncomfortable: how short and easy the code gets, only because the structure of the interval list is adapted to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if your interval list begins from 0 you can use this code :

```
string = 'anexample'
result = []
interval_list = [[0,0],[2,5]]

for i in range(len(interval_list)) :
    current_interval = interval_list[i]
    result.append(" ")
    result.append(string[current_interval[0]:current_interval[1]+1])
    result.append(" ")
    if i < len(interval_list) - 1 :
        next_interval = interval_list[i+1]
        result.append(string[current_interval[1]+1:next_interval[0]])
    if i == len(interval_list) - 1 :
        if string[current_interval[1]+1:] is not '' :
            result.append(string[current_interval[1]+1:])

output : [' ', 'a', ' ', 'n', ' ', 'exam', ' ', 'ple']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'anexample'
result = []
interval_list = [[0,0],[2,5]]


# Step 1:turn string into element list
string_list = list(string) #['a', 'n', 'e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e']

# Step 2: we want to insert " " according to the interval_list, but each time we insert one element, the next index
#will be influenced. So we convert the index into a new_interval_list that can predict the possible change
new_interval_list =  [[None for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(2)] # it should have identical shape to the interval_list

for i in range(len(interval_list)):
    #print(str(i))
    for j in range(2):
        #print(str(j))
        if j == 0: # first interval in a list
            new_interval_list[i][j] = interval_list[i][j] + i * 2
            #print(new_interval_list)
        else: # second interval in a list
            new_interval_list[i][j] = interval_list[i][j] + 2 + i * 2
            #print(new_interval_list)

# the new_interval_list returns [[0, 2], [4, 9]]

# Step 3: we turn [[0, 2], [4, 9]] into [0,2,4,9]
import itertools
new_interval_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(new_interval_list))

# Step 4: now we can insert " " into the list
for item in new_interval_list:
    string_list.insert(item," ")
    # [' ', 'a', ' ', 'n', ' ', 'e', 'x', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'p', 'l', 'e']

# Step 5: to get ['a', 'n', 'exam', 'ple']

tem_l = ("".join(string_list)).split() # ['a', 'n', 'exam', 'ple']

# step 6: get result, add " " between each item in the tem_l
for i in range(4):
    result.append(" ")
    result.append(tem_l[i])


result
```

Comment: The good thing about this method is that it won't be limited only to interval lists starting with 0. It can be generally applied.